# How can I compile a Lazarus Apache module to Apache 1.3, 2.0 and 2.2 selectively?

Tags: lazarus, fpc, apache-modules

I've had a look at /etc/fpc.cfg and there is mention to some defines:

- FPCAPACHE_1_3
- FPCAPACHE_2_0

Then in the fcl-web examples there is mention to:

- Apache1_3

The only one I've found is on the apr.pas on both these files:

- /usr/share/fpcsrc/2.4.0/packages/httpd20/src/apr/apr.pas
- /usr/share/fpcsrc/2.4.0/packages/httpd22/src/apr/apr.pas

So how does the compiler decide what version of APR to compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable the right one of those conditionals/directives afaik, the rest of the fpc.cfg should put the corresponding httpd dir first in the compilers search path, so that that version gets taken.

So you should only define one of them.

Comment: I guess somewher near the top of the config file. It is part of the configuration of FPC.

Comment: yes. I don't know if Lazarus overrides that though. Most my server app attempts always have been FPC only.

Comment: Oky, fpc.cfg it will be. I'll keep in mind the fact that Lazarus can override it and, if so, will probably comment here or add another question. And thanks again Marco!!