# Building mod_helloworld.lpr

Tags: apache2, lazarus, fpc, apache-modules

Im trying to build the apache example of the mod_helloworld.lpr, C:\lazarus\components\fpweb\demo\helloworld\apache

> Lazarus 0.9.29
>   FPC Verion 2.4.3  SVN 27129
>   i386-win32

After Adding `$(LazarusDir)\fpc\2.4.3\source\packages\fcl-web\src\` to the Other Unit Files (-Fu) it will compile, but when i build/link i get the errors

```
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterCustomImageList
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterMenuItem
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterMenu
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterMainMenu
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterPopupMenu
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterDragImageList
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterControl
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterWinControl
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterGraphicControl
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterCustomControl
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterScrollingWinControl
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterScrollBox
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterCustomFrame
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterCustomForm
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Error: Undefined symbol: WSRegisterHintWindow
mod_helloworld.lpr(38,1) Fatal: There were 15 errors compiling module, stopping
```

im gussing its trying to add the lcl or something, but really i have no idea.

Comment: BTW, here is the first article from Leonardo Ramé about Apache 2.2 module with both Delphi and FPC: http://leonardorame.blogspot.com/2009/04/apache-22x-modules-with-delphi.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out... it think

after adding `Interfaces` to the uses cause, i can get the mod_helloworld to compile.

I dont know where that came from, but i remember doing it to get a CGI co compile.

but the problem is now, my apache install will not except the .dll

LoadModule mod_helloworld "C:\lazarus\components\fpweb\demo\helloworld\apache\mod_helloworld.dll"

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 63 of
>   C:/Program Files/Apache Software
>   Foundatio n/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf:
>   Cannot load
>   C:/lazarus/components/fpweb/demo/hellow
>   orld/apache/mod_helloworld.dll into
>   server: The specified module could not
>   be found.

but ill prob post this as a new question soon

Comment: You have .so in the config file and .dll is what you should have. Could it be a problem with a mismatched extension?

Comment: yeh noticed that after i posted the answer/question, changed it back to .dll a still no change

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same exact problem under Ubuntu 10.04 LTS amd64.

Have a look at [Problem compiling a WebLaz project under Lazarus.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971770)

This one might also help: [How can I compile a Lazarus Apache module to Apache 1.3, 2.0 and 2.2 selectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971642)

I took the "delete unnecessary folders" option and forcing fpc.cfg to always point to httpd22.

I know it's not the best so I'll give a more detailed explanation.

Let's assume that FPSRC contains the FPC source files path, FPCUNITS contains the pre-compiled units and FPCCFG contains the path to the fpc.cfg file.

If you have a look at FPCCFG you'll find a block that decides what version of Apache:

```
#IFDEF FPCAPACHE_1_3
-Fu/usr/lib/fpc/$fpcversion/units/$fpctarget/httpd13/
#ELSE
#IFDEF FPCAPACHE_2_0
-Fu/usr/lib/fpc/$fpcversion/units/$fpctarget/httpd20/
#ELSE
-Fu/usr/lib/fpc/$fpcversion/units/$fpctarget/httpd22/
#ENDIF
#ENDIF
```

As per suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971642/how-can-i-compile-a-lazarus-apache-module-to-apache-1-3-2-0-and-2-2-selectively/3972578#3972578) you can put those directives at the top of FPCCFG so the compiler can reach the right folders.

So that takes care of where FPC can find the sources if it needs to compile them.

Now we have another problem: It's doesn't link against the right ppu.

If you have a look at FPCUNITS you'll find 3 folders: httpd13, httpd20 and httpd22.

Now the compiler, while looking for the correct folder/unit combination, will find it first under httpd13, or httpd20. This is no good if you want an Apache 2.2 module and will botch up all the linking.

I don't have a "smart" solution for this dilemma, one that involves conditional directives, so I just deleted the 2 folders I don't want(After a proper backup just in case I need to compile/link against other Apache versions). In my case httpd13 and httpd20.

I've also had to add the "-fPIC" to my compiler options. It was suggested in one of the error messages from either the compiler or the linker, but this is the only thing I REALLY DON'T KNOW if it's a global thing or just my 64bit setup.

I hope this works under Windows though.

**EDIT**: I'm building a multiple app project and will be using fpmake.pp to compile it all. Once I get all the kinks out of the fpmake.pp I'll also post it so one could avoid some of these issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have renamed the http13, and http20 folders allready. and i just tried the -fPIC compiler option with no change.

from what i can see, fPiC option looks like a gcc option, http://lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,4298.0.html